# Complex vector transpose returns result with wrong signs: MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, transpose

In matlab I have a matrix `As`

```
As = zeros(m, n);
```

Next I assign values to `As` and transpose the specific columns:

```
for idx = 1:n
   % Assign value to As, then assign to 'a' and 's'
   a = As(:, idx)';
   s = As(:, idx);
end
```

Then `s` is a column vector like:

```
s = [0.1 - 0.2i
     0.3 + 0.4i]
```

But elements in `a` have the flipped signs:

```
a = [0.1 + 0.2i, 0.3 - 0.4i]
```

This is confusing me, I mean the transpose of `s` should be a row (no problem) with the symbols in the order `-`, `+` like

```
a = [0.1 - 0.2i, 0.3 + 0.4i]
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prime operator `'` in matlab is actually an alias to [ctranspose](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html), which does not only convert rows to columns, or columns to rows of ordinary matrices or vectors, but also **calculates the complex conjugate**, i.e. changes the sign of the imaginary part.

> The non-conjugate transpose operator `A.'`, performs a transpose without conjugation. That is, it doesn't change the imaginary parts of the elements.

Comment: Oh,I see ,I have thought .' is the same as '  。 Now I have a better understand of them.Thanks,I learn a lot from it.

Comment: Mark Aki's answer as accepted if it helped you.